# PsFCIV_2.5.ps1 cannot be loaded. A Certificate chain could not be build to a trusted root authority

Tags: powershell

I run the following to import the function to my powershell, but this error occurs:

> . :\FCIV\PsFCIV_2.5.ps1 cannot be loaded. A Certificate chain could  not be build to a trusted root authority

How should I resolve this?

Comment: That error occurs because you don't trust the code signing certificate used to sign PsFCIV_2.5.ps1. Change your execution policy or run `Unblock-File` against the script

Comment: Thanks mathias, Can you provide me the entire commands to run the unblock-file.

Comment: I have change the executionpolicy to "Allsigned" and i am still having the same error.

Comment: `AllSigned` won't work, neither will `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: i have run the unblock-file -path PsFCIV_2.5.ps1 as well. Somehow i still getting the same error, when loading the PsFCIV_2.5.ps1